# How to detect/workaound a fully transparent screenshot on applicationDidEnterBackground?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, screenshot, multitasking

I'm using this snippet of code to save a screenshot on applicationDidEnterBackground, which is presented later as the loading screen while the scene is loading in the background.

```
@implementation CCDirector(ScreenShot)

+(void)saveScreenshotWithFilename: (NSString*) filename {
    [CCDirector sharedDirector].nextDeltaTimeZero = YES;

    CGSize winSize = CCDirector.sharedDirector.winSize;
    CCRenderTexture * renderTexture = [CCRenderTexture renderTextureWithWidth:winSize.width
                                                                       height:winSize.height
                                                                  pixelFormat:kCCTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888
                                                           depthStencilFormat:GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT16];

    [renderTexture beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0 depth:1.0f];
    [CCDirector.sharedDirector.runningScene visit];
    [renderTexture end];

    UIImage *image = [renderTexture getUIImage];

    NSString *filePath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/%@", filename];

    [UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
}

@end
```

It works ok, but in the case when the user taps the app icon to run the app, then pulses the home button, then taps the app icon again in a quick succession, the resulting screenshot is a transparent PNG file, with the right dimensions, but fully transparent.

How can I check for this special case to present some other image as the loading screen?

...or better yet, is there a workaround for the transparent screenshot?

Comment: run a timer in willenterforeground and only take screenshot if the app has been in foreground for x seconds

Comment: @LearnCocos2D That's better than my current approach, which is to put the default loading screen in a CCSprite and call `[sprite visit]` before `[CCDirector.sharedDirector.runningScene visit]` when taking the screenshot